# Print list as array Python

Tags: python

I have a list with elements like (x,y,value) how can I print that list as array where all the elements of the list with x are on the same line?

I tried this but it doesn’t work

```
def print_list(l,size):
    for x in l: 
        print x[2]
```

My main problem is that I don't know how to print elements of the list in the same line, cause this way it prints each element in a new line.

Edit: I wasn't clear enough my list simulates an array eg for size=2 my list would have elements like this:

```
[0,0,value1]
[0,1,value2]
[1,0,value3]
[1,1,value3]
```

My functions prints it this way:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

I want to modify my function in order to be printed like this:

```
value1 value2
value3 value4
```

Comment: `print x[0],` Thats it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

This should work:

```
def print_list(l,size):
    for n in range(0, len(l), size):
        values = [str(x[2]) for x in l[n:n+size]]
        print(' '.join(values))
```

Original answer:

Using [the `print` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print):

```
def print_list(l,size):
    for x in l: 
        print x[2],
```

or using [the `print` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print):

```
from __future__ import print_function
def print_list(l,size):
    for x in l: 
        print(x[2], end='')
```

Note: adding the comma after the `print` statement adds a space after the string you print. If you don't want the space, then it's best to use the `print` function.

Comment: I tried to keep your coding style intact. However, you really should separate parameters by a space: ``def print_list(l, size):``. Also, you shouldn't use ``l`` as a variable name. It's too easy to misread. If you really want ``l`` for list, try ``L`` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_list(l,size):
    for x in l: 
        print x[0]
```

Comment: He wants the elements in the same line, you might want to use `print x[0],`

Answer (score 0):

[`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html), or pretty print, is pretty fantastic for this type of thing. Out of the box, it won't give you output exactly like you are asking about, but it's flexible enough to work for a lot of other situations as well.

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(l, width=width)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can generate arrays in the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) module that, when printed, arrange their entries into neat rows and columns.

```
import numpy

lst = [('a',1,'hi'), ('b',2,'my'), ('c',3,'name'), ('d',4,'is')]
arr = numpy.array(lst)
print(arr)
```

If you want to see `1,2,3,4` on the same row as opposed to in the same column, transpose the array.

```
arr_t = arr.transpose()
print(arr_t)
```

Hope this helps. If I misunderstood your question, don't hesitate to point it out.